# Generic and a Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, generics, stored-procedures

I'm sure this has been asked; but I can't find the exact context.  Would this be a novice or ill-advised approach?  Or is this an acceptable approach.

I have a project in which I'm working on.  I have these four tables:

- Customer
- Address
- Site
- Login

So the database is basic, nothing too crazy.

But I've created a `Restful Service` to link my Client to my Server.  Which to perform my Crud Operation will require a simple `Insert Command`.

Like:

```
 string sqlInsertStr = "INSERT INTO Customer (First, Last, Phone, Email) 
         VALUES (@first, @last, @phone, @email)";
```

So that'd handle one of my four tables; my thought was one of these two approaches:

1. Use a `Generic` to store each individual Query; then loop to iterate each query.
2. Use a `Generic` that contains a series of `Stored Procedures` to iterate through.

My goal is to avoid several `strings` to iterate through and write to the database.

My reasoning was, when a client modifies an individual field or an entire profile; it would handle all the tables congruently.  In `SQL` I know it has limitations when trying to insert data across multiple tables.

Is that a bad approach; this particular is fairly small and simple.  So I'm not looking to go to crazy; but it is for school.  So I'm trying to understand if I'm even coming up with a valid solution, and if I am is it considered a right solution?

Any input on the matter and explanation would be terrific.

---

**Update:**

I apologize for the confusion; yes I have one Object Model- which contains all the information for each column of each table.  My question is this:

`SQL` does not like `Inserting` across multiple tables.  So this works just fine for one table:

```
using (connection)
{
      string sqlInsertStr = "INSERT INTO Customer (First, Last, Phone, Email) 
             VALUES (@first, @last, @phone, @email)";
      connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
      command = new SqlCommand();
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.Connection.Open();
      command.CommandText = sqlInsertStr;

      SqlParameter firstParam = new SqlParameter(@"first", cust.First);
      SqlParameter lastParam = new SqlParameter(@"last", cust.Last);
      SqlParameter phoneParam = new SqlParameter(@"phone", cust.Phone);
      SqlParameter emailParam = new SqlParameter(@"email", cust.Email);

      command.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[] 
              { firstParam, lastParam, phoneParam, emailParam});
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      command.Connection.Close();
}
```

That will easily write to the one table; but what about all the other data that needs to be inserted to those other tables?  Would I need to create a `sqlInsertStr` for each table?  Or couldn't I simply do something like this:

```
using(connection)
{
     list<string> sqlInsertStr = new list<string>();
     sqlInsertStr.Add("INSERT INTO Customer (First, Last, Phone, Email) 
              VALUES (@first, @last, @phone, @email)"l
     sqlInsertStr.Add("INSERT INTO Address (Street, City, State, Zip, Country)
               VALUES (@Street, @City, @State, @Zip, @Country)";

     connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
     command = new SqlCommand();
     command.Connection = connection;
     command.CommandText = sqlInsertStr;

     // Repeat with Parameters and etc.
}
```

So wouldn't essentially using a `Generic` or `StringBuilder` allow me to just include one string to handle all those Inserts with the proper data?  Or am I completely over-thinking / confusing myself.  I'm still learning, so an explanation would be great.

Comment: Why use generics at all? That confuses me. You want to execute multiple SQL statements, but _don't_ want to iterate through a list of them? Why?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. What is `Generic`? Do you have object model for Contact, Address and Site?

Comment: I added an update. To hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [numerous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generic+repository) here on making it work, I would recommend not trying to be clever by genericizing too much.  My recommended approach for any problem is:

1. Make it work - by any means necessary (even {gasp} copy-and-paste)
2. Make it better - refactoring, genericizing, etc.
3. Make it faster - by profiling and looking at the SLOWEST pieces first

Too many people try to do 2) and 3) before it even *works* and end up spending more time hacking or micro-optimizing just to get it to work.  If you get it to work first, you can always throw away your optimizations and start over, and you still have a working product!

All that to say, don't worry about generics yet - create four repositories (one for each table), then analyze and see if Generics can make is cleaner.

**Comment on your update**

> am I completely over-thinking / confusing myself

It sounds like it.  Don't try to make one class handle CRUD operations for all types just to avoid using the same connection/command code in multiple places.  Each repository (and I'm using that term loosely, meaning some class that handles the CRUD operations) should have its own connection/command code.  If later you decide that you can create a base class that deals with the grunge work, that's fine - or you can use a ORM layer like Entity Framework or NHibernate to handle that for you.  Or you can have a mixture.  Whatever works best AFTER you get it to work. :)

Comment: @ta.speot.is good point - if only there was [a process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) for that...

Comment: Thank you for the comment, your mentioned the Repository pattern.  I've yet to dabble into it in a lot of depth.  I'll look into it- thank you. I did update the question though.

Comment: @D Stanley that actually makes valid sense.  I just know that one insert statement will fail; as Sql doesn't like multiple tables in a single statement.  Was trying to be very, very simple that is why I thought why not just add a simple list.  Thank you for the explanation.